# Meteor Mongodb count fields in nested object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to create a dashboard where I show summaries of order data within the app. In this case I am simply wanting count the number of items in a given category in my Orders collection. My code so far looks like this:

Collection data

```
{
    "_id" : "a6wHiXxyM5DwSAsfq",
    "orderNumber" : 1234,
    "createdAt" : "11/01/2016, 14:43:49",
    "productsInOrder" : [
        {
            "category" : "ambient",
            "item" : 50818,
            "desc" : "Tasty Rubber Chicken",
            "quantity" : "44",
            "price" : "0.92",
            "lineprice" : "40.48",
            "_id" : "FFNxG8vujs6NGN69r"
        },
        {
            "category" : "frozen",
            "item" : 71390,
            "desc" : "Generic Granite Fish",
            "quantity" : "11",
            "price" : "1.00",
            "lineprice" : "11.00",
            "_id" : "LcRtpyLxkWyh39kkB"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "PdpywXCvfew7qojmA",
    "orderNumber" : 1234,
    "createdAt" : "11/01/2016, 14:44:15",
    "productsInOrder" : [
        {
            "category" : "frozen",
            "item" : 71390,
            "desc" : "Generic Granite Fish",
            "quantity" : "44",
            "price" : "1.00",
            "lineprice" : "44.00",
            "_id" : "dAscx4R8pcBgbzoZs"
        },
        {
            "category" : "frozen",
            "item" : 66940,
            "desc" : "Gorgeous Granite Bike",
            "quantity" : "55",
            "price" : "4.21",
            "lineprice" : "231.55",
            "_id" : "xm3mFRmPmmdPxjfP9"
        },
        {
            "category" : "frozen",
            "item" : 96029,
            "desc" : "Gorgeous Plastic Fish",
            "quantity" : "1234",
            "price" : "4.39",
            "lineprice" : "5417.26",
            "_id" : "7u7SHnpTf7PWcrhGA"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "xcHZ25qwvyDpDJtAZ",
    "orderNumber" : 1234,
    "createdAt" : "11/01/2016, 14:44:47",
    "productsInOrder" : [
        {
            "category" : "frozen",
            "item" : 31104,
            "desc" : "Handcrafted Rubber Keyboard",
            "quantity" : "11",
            "price" : "4.78",
            "lineprice" : "52.58",
            "_id" : "LMMwbKFEgnCbgCt9c"
        },
        {
            "category" : "frozen",
            "item" : 77832,
            "desc" : "Practical Rubber Shirt",
            "quantity" : "21",
            "price" : "0.62",
            "lineprice" : "13.02",
            "_id" : "63otkkXWGrTJkwEgX"
        },
        {
            "category" : "frozen",
            "item" : 66940,
            "desc" : "Gorgeous Granite Bike",
            "quantity" : "111",
            "price" : "4.21",
            "lineprice" : "467.31",
            "_id" : "rbPSujey8CFeMPjza"
        }
    ]
}
```

JS

So far I have tried:

```
Orders.find({ 'productsInOrder': ['ambient']}).count();
Orders.find({ productsInOrder: { category: 'ambient' }}).count();
Orders.find({ productsInOrder: { $all: [ 'frozen' ] }}).count();
```

I am having a hard time understanding Mongo queries when the data is nested in this manner. Please can you help point me in the right direction? Many thanks in advance.

*** SOLUTION ***

I have accomplished the desired result thanks to the contributions below. To make this work I created a method on the server as the query cannot be run on the client using an existing collection. This is done as follows:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'byCategory': function() {
    var result = Orders.aggregate([
        { "$unwind": "$productsInOrder" },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": null,
                "ambient_count": {
                    "$sum": {
                        "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$productsInOrder.category", "ambient" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                    }
                },
                "frozen_count": {
                    "$sum": {
                        "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$productsInOrder.category", "frozen" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                    }
                },
                "other_category_count": {
                    "$sum": {
                        "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$productsInOrder.category", "other_category" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]);

    return result;
  }
})
```

and then on the client:

```
Meteor.call('byCategory', function( error, result ) {
  if( error ) {
    console.log( error.reason );
  } else {
    console.log( result[0].ambient_count );
    console.log( result[0].frozen_count );
    etc....
  }
});
```

Thanks and credit to @chridam and @Brett.

Comment: I believe there is a way to simply group by category (frozen, ambient, etc.) and then count. Try this in mongo: db.orders.aggregate([{$unwind: "$productsInOrder"}, {$group: {_id: "$productsInOrder.category", count: {$sum: 1}}}]); For your purposes, you would need to do this in meteor: Orders.aggregate([{"$unwind": "$productsInOrder" },{"$group": {"_id": "$productsInOrder.category","count": {"$sum": 1}}}]);

Comment: Thanks @Brett I'll give this a go and report back, it does seem a more simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach is to use the **[`aggregation framework`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)**. Consider the following aggregation pipeline which as the first stage of the aggregation pipeline, the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator denormalizes the `productsInOrder` array to output for each input document, `n` documents where n is the number of array elements. The next pipeline stage has the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator which groups all the documents into a single document and stores the counts for each category with the help of the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** and **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operators.

In Meteor, you can then use **[meteorhacks:aggregate package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate)** to implement the aggregation:

Add to your app with

```
meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate
```

Note, this only works on server side and there is no oberserving support or reactivity built in. Then simply use **`.aggregate`** function like below.

```
var coll = new Mongo.Collection('orders');
var pipeline = [
    { "$unwind": "$productsInOrder" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null, 
            "ambient_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$productsInOrder.category", "ambient" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "frozen_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$productsInOrder.category", "frozen" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "other_category_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$productsInOrder.category", "other_category" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            }
        }
    }       
];
var result = coll.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Running the same pipeline in mongo shell using the sample data will yield:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "ambient_count" : 1,
            "frozen_count" : 7,
            "other_category_count" : 0
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

---

You can access the native mongo collection and publish the aggregation results to the orders collection on the client side:

```
Meteor.publish('categoryCounts', function() {  
    var self = this,
        db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;

    orders = db.collection("orders").aggregate(pipeline, // Need to wrap the callback so it gets called in a Fiber.
        Meteor.bindEnvironment(
            function(err, result) {
                // Add each of the results to the subscription.
                _.each(result, function(e) {
                    self.added("orders", e._id, e);
                });
                self.ready();
            },
            function(error) {
                Meteor._debug( "Error doing aggregation: " + error);
            }
        )
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there any way to use this on an existing collection? I get an error that the collection exists if I use the way you stated above. Alternatively if I simply run `Orders.aggregate()` I get an error saying  aggregate is not a function. I have installed the package correctly with all dependencies.

Comment: @mtwallet Just meteor add `meteorhacks:aggregate` and you should be in business. This will add an aggregate method to your collections. I've also provided another approach where you can access the mongodb native driver and thus use the underlying methods to run the aggregation operation.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do this within Meteor, you will need to use mongo aggregation. Minimongo doesn't include aggregation though, so you will need this package to accomplish it:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/

I only tested this in mongo itself, so you will have to adapt it to the way that the aggregation package does it:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$productsInOrder"
    }, 
    {
        $match: {
            "productsInOrder.category": "frozen"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null, 
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
         }
     }
]);
```

The first part is unwinding the collection. It will basically make an "order" entry for every instance of $productsInOrder. Once you have the array flattened out, we match on the category you care about; in this case, the "frozen" category. Next we group it up so we can count the number of documents returned. $group is simply constructing the final object that will be output from the query. You can modify this to be whatever you want, or you could group by productsInOrder.category and not even $match on "frozen".

Comment: Hi @Brett thanks for the help, I appreciate it. When I try this I get a value of three back. There are currently a total of 7 instances in the collection. Its like it only pulls one instance of 'frozen' from each. I will update my collection to reflect what I'm talking about.

Comment: Ah, so the query I posted will only look through these items on a per order basis...let me come up with a new solution.

Comment: Yes thats the part I'm struggling with, summing all within each order.

Comment: I updated my answer, but it appears @chridam posted a pretty decent solution!

Comment: Indeed! A little head scratching and figuring out to do on my part. Thanks again for all your help, it's much appreciated.